# Trying to log a data object in the console using dot notation and it doesn't work, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, nosql

I have a React project using Graphql and Mongo. When doing a query, I'm trying to log the returned data in the console through dot notation and it return "undefined".

I can't fathom Why??

**My Component:**

```
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { GET_USER_SETTINGS } from "../graphql/getUserTimeSetting";

const UserAuthSettings = ({ isAuthenticated, toggle, user = { name: "" } }) => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_USER_SETTINGS, {
    variables: { userName: user.name },
    options: {
      awaitRefetchQueries: true,
    },
  });

  console.log(data.userTimeSetting);

 
  if (loading) return <div>Submitting...</div>;
  if (error) return <div>{error.message}</div>;

  return null;
};

export default UserAuthSettings;
```

**Console**
[image]

**If I only "console.log(data)**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the answer.

To use or "consume" the data with Apollo/client hooks, you need to do it once you make sure the data exist.

In other words, the code block

```
if (loading) return <div>Submitting...</div>;
  if (error) return <div>{error.message}</div>;
```

must come before my console.log(data) - otherwise the query is still in flight and react could not verify the existence of the data. Hence the error.

Fantastic, moving one.

Comment: Yes, `data` can legitimately be undefined(not only on initial render but also if request fails). And yes, you either make `if()` to check this case, or use [optional chainging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), or use helpers like lodash's [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get).